# The right way to dynamically control location tracking (registering / unregistering location broadcast receiver)

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, locationmanager

I want to dynamically control location tracking (registering / unregistering location broadcast receiver). This is how I am planning to do it. I have two questions :

1. What are the mistakes in the implementation below because all this concept is still very theoretical to me as I am very new to android/java dev. Still building concepts!
2. How do I pass some EXTRA_INFO from my location library class to the location receiver.

**IMPLEMENTATION:**

I have a library class LocationLibrary.java which consists of two methods. They do as the name suggest. The location tracking should start when I call startTracking(). Plz note the extraInfo that needs to be passed to myLocationReceiver. The tracking should stop when stopTracking() is called.

Code snippet:

```
public class LocationLibraray
{
    private static BroadcastReceiver myLocationReceiver;

    public LocationLibraray(Context context)
    {
        this.ctx = context;
        myLocationReceiver = new MyLocationReceiver();
    }

    public void startTracking(Context context, String extraInfo)
    {
         IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
         filter.addAction("com.app.android.tracker.LOCATION_READY");
         context.registerReceiver(myLocationReceiver, filter);

        // NEED TO PASS extraInfo to myLocationReceiver for some processing, but HOW?
    }

    public void stopTracking(Context context)
    {
        context.unregisterReceiver(locationReceiver);
    }
```

}

MyLocationReceiver.java

```
public class MyLocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  {

    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ((intent.getAction() != null) && 
                (intent.getAction().equals("com.app.android.tracker.LOCATION_READY")))
        {
             //GET THAT EXTRA INFO FROM LocationLibrary class and process it here
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me out. Thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not add a constructor to MyLocationReceiver?

```
public class MyLocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 String info = "";

 public MyLocationReceiver(String extraInfo)
 {
     this.info = extraInfo;

 }
 ........
 public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
     if ((intent.getAction() != null) && 
                (intent.getAction().equals("com.app.android.tracker.LOCATION_READY")))
        {
             if (info.contains("Hi"))
                 //do some stuff
        }
    }


}
```

And you would instantiate it like this:

```
myLocationReceiver = new MyLocationReceiver(new String("Hello!"));
```

Comment: Oops! That was a bummer :P. Ofcourse a constructor will do the job. How did I miss that. Thanks Jack :)!